# How to update an active record in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to update status to 1, when user views a message.

i need an active record, to change status to 1 ,where status is 0 and id is current id

Any help is appreciated. 
i want to change this query to active record.

`UPDATE 'course_queries SET status = '1' WHERE course_queries.id =41 and status=0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nithin mentioned, ActiveRecord is a rails feature. Thus, the following wouldn't work unless you're using the Ruby on Rails framework.

With that said, you could also try:

```
@course = CourseQuery.where(id: params[:id], status: 0).each do |q|
    q.update(status: 1)
end
```

If you need it all in one line, you could use:

```
@course = CourseQuery.where(id: params[:id], status: 0).update_all(status: 1)
```

You can then change the id or status here dynamically. :)

Since these examples use the update and update_all methods, I'd recommend you read up about them. Here's a great article I've found on the differences: [Difference between active record methods – update, update_all, update_attribute, update_attributes](https://priyankapathak.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/difference-between-active-record-methods-update-update_all-update_attribute-update_attributes/)

Comment: if please can you avoid this looping and give answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by looping. What's happening?

Comment: how to write without adding each loop

Comment: Ah, gotcha. You could use the Rails update_all method. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

Using ActiveRecord.

```
@course_query = CourseQuery.find(params[:id]) #id is 41 from your comment
  if @course_query.status == 0
     @course_query.status = 1 
     @course_query.save
  end
```

Comment: ActiveRecord can be perfectly used on his own without rails